# Is there a benefit to explicit use of "new EventHandler" declaration?

Tags: c#, .net

In assigning event handlers to something like a context `MenuItem`, for instance, there are two acceptable syntaxes:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Open Image", btnOpenImage_Click);
```

...and...

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Open Image", new EventHandler(btnOpenImage_Click));
```

I also note that the same appears to apply to this:

```
listView.ItemClick += listView_ItemClick;
```

...and...

```
listView.ItemClick += new ItemClickEventHandler(listView_ItemClick);
```

Is there any particular advantage for the second (explicit) over the first?  Or is this more of a stylistic question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C# 1.0 you had no choice but to explicitly define the delegate type and the target.

Since C# 2.0 the compiler allows you to express yourself in a more succinct manner by means of an implicit conversion from a method group to a compatible delegate type. It's really just syntactic sugar.

Sometimes you have no choice but to use the long-winded syntax if the correct overload cannot be resolved from the method group due to an ambiguity.

Comment: This sums it up quite nicely.  @keyboardP adds a lot to the answer with the explanation of event handler assign/unassign benefits.

Answer (score 9):

It's syntax for older version of C# compiler (<=1.1). Not needed anymore. Current compilers are sophisticated enough to get it right.

There's one (little) benefit, sometimes. If you assign event handlers by "+=", the Intellisense autocomplete feature may make writing code a bit faster.

Comment: This syntax was no longer needed in .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

The **only** time when this is useful is if it would otherwise be ambiguous - for example, if it was `MenuItem(string, Delegate)` - of if there were multiple **equally matching** overloads that would match the signature. This also includes `var` syntax (shown below) and generic type inference (not shown):

```
EventHandler handler = SomeMethod; // fine
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(SomeMethod); // fine
var handler = new EventHandler(SomeMethod); // fine
var handler = (EventHandler)SomeMethod; // fine
var handler = SomeMethod; // not fine
```

In all other cases, it is redundant and is unnecessary in any compiler from 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

Related to your edit - The adding of handlers isn't really affected by using `new` or not but there's a slight difference in *removing* handlers like this

```
listView.ItemClick -= listView_ItemClick;
```

and

```
listView.ItemClick -= new ItemClickEventHandler(listView_ItemClick);
```

albeit unlikely to affect most scenarios. The first version, without the `new` keyword, is supposedly more efficient.

There's a detailed explanation in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/08/26/456437.aspx) but the conclusion is

> So both works but which one should we use? If the events are
>   subscribed/unsubscribed once at the beginning/end like in a typical
>   WinForm application then it hardly matters. However if this is done
>   multiple times then the second approach is preferable as it does less
>   of costly heap allocations and will work faster

(second approach in that post being the one without the `new` keyword)

Having said that it seems like a micro optimization to me so it's unlikely to be a bottleneck in the majority of cases.

Comment: Ultimately, @ByteBlast answered the general question pretty well, but +1 for adding this answer, it provides quite a lot.