# multiple options for event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using c# Win Forms with Resharper and it  gives me three options for event handler:

eg:

1.`button.Click+= (sender, args) => ;`

2.`button.Click+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) {  };`

3.`button3.Click+= Button3OnClick;`

```
private void Button3OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{

}
```

So my questions are:

1. What are the differences between using one over the others?
2. Is there a preferred way I should stick with?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448305/is-there-a-benefit-to-explicit-use-of-new-eventhandler-declaration/17448413#17448413

Comment: I assume you use Resharper , so you can know that they are the same.

Comment: Fourth option `butto3.Click += new EventHandler(Button3OnClick);`

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy that's same as third option

Comment: @user2114862 your first two options also exactly same

Answer (score 1):

As everyone will tell you, they are equivalent.

One important thing to note though

from [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

> It is important to notice that you cannot easily unsubscribe from an
>   event if you used an anonymous function to subscribe to it. To
>   unsubscribe in this scenario, it is necessary to go back to the code
>   where you subscribe to the event, store the anonymous method in a
>   delegate variable, and then add the delegate to the event. In general,
>   we recommend that you do not use anonymous functions to subscribe to
>   events if you will have to unsubscribe from the event at some later
>   point in your code.

Comment: thank you. I marked your answer as correct as it gives most explanation + useful link.

Answer (score 1):

> 3) button3.Click += Button3OnClick;

Here you attach delegate which referes to named method `Button3OnClick`.

> 2) button.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) { };

Here you declare anonymous method in .NET 1.1 style. And attach [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) which referes to this anonymous method. Compiler will generate ordinal named method for this anonymous method, so acutally that is same as

```
button.Click += CompilerGeneratedName;
```

Where

```
private void CompilerGeneratedName(object sender, EventArgs args)
{  
}
```

On .NET version > 3 you unlikely will use this syntax, because it was simplified with lambdas.

> 1) button.Click += (sender, args) => ;

That is *exactly same* as previous case, but written in [lambda syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Compiler will generate named method for this anonymous method.

All these options do same - they create and attach delegate which referers to method with required syntax. The only difference is the name of method - method gets name either before compilation, or during compilation.

> Is there a preferred way I should stick with?

Usually lambdas (i.e. anonymous methods) are used for very small methods, which just don't worth creating named method manually. But event handlers often not that simple. So, I personally don't like having part of handlers named, and part of attached in-place, because I like to keep code in consistent way. I also like to see usages of event handler, have ability to unsubscribe handler from event, and handler name in stack. So I stick with named handlers. But you always should use same guidlines as your team does.

Comment: Thanks for very clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on events and delegates : [Delegates and Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx)

But what it boils down to is that option 3 was always the defacto standard for creating events in .net 2. Since .net 3 delegates got introduced and made it easier to implement with the short hand, option 1 and option 2.

a delegate as used above specifies a place holder containing a signature and return type, the code inside the delegate describes the interactions.

If your learning about events , use option 3 to get your head around it. If you think you have the hang of delegates use option 2. And when it starts boring you to type out everything use option 1

:)